# Sorting with 2 keys and combining both

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, indexing

I have a file called "name_score_smiles.csv" which looks like this:

```
('VA00001', '64.11', '33.12', 'Cl.O=C1Nc2ccc(N)cc2C1')
('VA00002', '70.61', '54', 'CNCCC(=O)c1ccccc1')
('VA00003', '53.15', '57.76', 'O=c1[nH]c2cnccc2n1c1ccccc1')
('VA00004', '72.08', '41.82', 'CN1CCC(CC1)Nc1ccc(F)c(Cl)c1')
('VA00005', '67.11', '57.17', 'CCN1CCC(CC1)Nc1ccc(Cl)cc1')
('VA00006', '66.29', '48.66', 'O=C1Nc2cc3OCCOc3cc2C(C1)c1ccccc1')
('VA00007', '70.59', '40.31', 'C=CCC1(CCCCC1)NCCc1ccccc1')
('VA00008', '62.87', '43.29', 'Clc1cccc(CN2CCN(CC2)Cc2c[nH]c3ccccc23)c1')
('VA00009', '70.53', '27.3', 'Clc1cccc(CNCCc2c[nH]c3ccccc23)c1')
('VA00010', '67.15', '51.88', 'O=C(Nc1ccccc1)N1CCCCC1c1cccnc1')
...
```

I have read it in as a list of lists and I know how to sort this file according to the second or third column. My script so far looks like this:

```
with open('name_score_smiles.csv') as fin:
        lst = list(csv.reader(fin))

lst_20 = sorted(lst, key=lambda x:float(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

What I would like to do is this:
I want to sort my list according to the second column and save the ranking. Then sort it according to the third column and save the ranking. So that in the end I can sort the entire file according to the rankings in both columns. Is it clear what I mean?

Thanks to everybody for your answers!!

Answer (score 2):

usually you'll use a `tuple` or some other sequence as a sort key for something like this:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (float(x[1]),float(x[2])), reverse=True)
```

At the end of the sort, you'll have your items ordered by decending column 2.  Where the values in column 2 are equal, then the comparison of column 3 will be used.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The values in column 3 are (almost) always lower than in column 2. They can't be directly compared with each other. I really have to sort according to the 2nd and 3rd column separately.